# SQL Server : using IN clause is very slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm creating a temporary table that is populated with the top 25 items for a specific user. I am then using this temporary table to get all the pieces for those items from another table.

These are my steps:

```
DECLARE @tableIds TABLE (id uniqueidentifier)

INSERT INTO @tableIds
    SELECT TOP 25 I.Id
    FROM Items I 
    INNER JOIN UserItems UI ON I.Id = UI.UserId
    WHERE UI.UserId = 'b846371d-5afc-eb11-b563-0003ff2a40c4'
      AND I.Valid = 1
    ORDER BY I.[TimeStamp] DESC
```

Now when I do a query on the items pieces using the IN clause on the id the query is very slow. Taking over 2 min to run and causing the app to timeout. There are only 1700 related rows in the item pieces table but there are over 2 million rows altogether. The query is like so:

```
SELECT 
    IPs.Id, 
    IPs.ItemId, 
    IPs.[Name], 
    IPs.PartNo, 
    IPs.PartPosition, 
    IPs.Size,
    IPs.Step
FROM
    ItemPieces IPs
WHERE 
    Ips.ItemId IN (SELECT id FROM @tableIds)
```

I thought about using and tried the `EXISTS` clause following numerous examples but I struggled to figure out how to get it work and return the related results. It was instead returning everything and not just the related rows.

How do I go about writing this so that I only get the related rows but it is fast as well?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an index on `ItemId`? What does the execution plan look like?

Comment: Have you tried just using a subquery instead of creating your temporary table?

Comment: Wouldn't an inner join make more sense here?

Comment: I would use a temporary table with his CREATE #table, not a declared one.

Comment: @SeanLange yes, I missed it! sorry. Thats why I deleted my comment and upvoted your comment.

Comment: I would avoid table variables like this. They do not allow indexing where a temp table does. But in this case a temp table or table variable just isn't needed. Either use a subquery or a cte and then an inner join.

Comment: @MartinSmith sorry but I'm still a bit green when it comes to SQL Server.  Since the ItemId can be N+ in the itempieces table I didn't think it could be indexed. If so I have much to learn.

Comment: @SeanLange how would you go about writing the inner join here?

Comment: ordering by timestamp is slow?  (Indexed?) ... top 25 based on newest item?  seems odd but ok.... what defines the top 25 you're after?  the fact that it's in the "newest" items purchanged?  Lastly,  `IN` vs `exists` and handling null values could be an issue...

Comment: @xQbert I can't agree more. There are so many likely performance issues in what have seen here.

Comment: IT seems odd the join would be on I.ID (Item's ID presumably) and UI.UserID (the USER ID?)  Shouldn't the UI.ItemID be used?  Please verify the Join criteria is on the correct table objects.

Comment: If you only need columns from one table a semi join (in/exists) is fine, an inner join doesn't make any "more sense"

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. I'm a 1 man shop doing everything so I'm still very green in many areas and learning more as I go.

Comment: @SeanLange `DECLARE @tableIds TABLE (id uniqueidentifier PRIMARY KEY)` will get you an index, as would `DECLARE @tableIds TABLE (id uniqueidentifier, INDEX CLUSTERED (id))

Comment: @Charlieface yes an index can be created on a table variable but only a unique index or a primary key.  Your second posted example is actually invalid. For an amazing read on the topic check out this post. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry you're right, it needs an index name `DECLARE @tableIds TABLE (id uniqueidentifier, INDEX IX CLUSTERED(id))`, but you *can* do a normal clustered or  non-clustered index, as well as includes see fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eb277d3e8ad96000d3f12d4d5442896c. I agree that a table variable isn't the right solution, and I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rework this to use an inner join to your limited list of values. Using your two queries it would be something like this.

```
SELECT IPs.Id, 
    IPs.ItemId, 
    IPs.[Name], 
    IPs.PartNo, 
    IPs.PartPosition, 
    IPs.Size,
    IPs.Step
FROM ItemPieces IPs
inner join 
(
    SELECT TOP 25 I.Id
    FROM Items I INNER JOIN
    UserItems UI on I.Id = UI.UserId
    WHERE UI.UserId = 'b846371d-5afc-eb11-b563-0003ff2a40c4'
    AND I.Valid = 1
    ORDER BY I.[TimeStamp] DESC 
) x on x.id = IPs.ItemId
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know you could do this. This was supper fast. From over 2 min down to around 2 seconds. Thank you. Thank you.

Comment: @MicahMontoya cool glad that worked for you.